# Add a Total and Count Row to a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follow:

```
dashboard = pd.DataFrame({
 'id':[1,2,3,4],
 'category': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'],
 'price': [123, 151, 21, 24],
 'description': ['IT related', 'IT related', 'Marketing','']
})
```

I need to add a row to show both sum and count only for some categories as follow:

```
pd.DataFrame({
 'id': [3],
 'category': ['a&b'],
 'price': [295],
 'description': ['']
})
```

Comment: for each pair of categories? of just specific ones?

Comment: just specif ones. in this case a&b

Comment: why `'id': [4]` and `'description': ['']` ?

Comment: you're right. it should be three (the number of ids in categories a and b). thanks! i edited it. about description, I want it blank

Comment: Whats the logic of your selection of categorys? Hard to understand what _"only for some categories as follow"_ means

Comment: I have three categories (a,b,c) but I only need that conclusion row for categories a and b though.

Answer (score 1):

An option using `.agg`:

```py
dashboard = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'category': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'],
    'price': [123, 151, 21, 24],
    'description': ['IT related', 'IT related', 'Marketing', '']
})
a_b = dashboard[dashboard['category'].isin(['a','b'])].agg({'id':'count', 'price':sum})
df = pd.DataFrame({'a&b':a_b})
```

yields

```py
       a&b
id       3
price  295
```

which you could then `.transpose()` and merge into your existing dataframe if desired, or compile a separate dataframe of summary results, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I pre-calculate all the sums for each category, then for each pair we add the sums, and the category names, and append the new row.

try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

dashboard = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'category': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'],
    'price': [123, 151, 21, 24],
    'description': ['IT related', 'IT related', 'Marketing', '']
})

pairs = [('a', 'b')]

groups = dashboard.groupby("category")['price'].sum()

for c1, c2 in pairs:
    new_id = sum((dashboard['category'] == c1) | (dashboard['category'] == c2))
    name = '{}&{}'.format(c1, c2)
    price_sum = groups[c1] + groups[c2]
    dashboard = dashboard.append(pd.DataFrame({'id': [new_id], 'category': [name], 'price': [price_sum], 'description': ['']}))

print(dashboard)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try this:

[image]

## Code

```
dashboard = pd.DataFrame({
 'id':[1,2,3,4],
 'category': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'],
 'price': [123, 151, 21, 24],
 'description': ['IT related', 'IT related', 'Marketing','']
})

selection =['a','b']
selection_row = '&'.join(selection)
df2 = dashboard[dashboard['category'].isin(selection)].agg({'id' : ['count'], 'price' : ['sum']}).fillna(0).T
df2['summary'] = df2['count'].add(df2['sum'])

df2.loc['description'] =np.nan
df2.loc['category'] = selection_row

final_df = df2['summary']

final_df

id               3
price          295
description    NaN
category       a&b
Name: summary, dtype: object
```